# TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm getting this error with this code

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
module.exports = {
    name: 'info',
    description: "Shows BOT's Informations",
    execute(message, client, args) {
        const MyUsername = client.guilds.resolve(testserver).members.resolve(creator).user
        const infoEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
```

The strange thing is that I have

`const MyUsername = client.guilds.resolve(testserver).mebers.resolve(creator).user`

even in my index.js and it works fine there.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Since you have `.resolve` twice in the same line, can you tell what is undefined? `client.guilds` or `client.guilds.resolve(testserver).members`? Also can you show what the value is of `testserver` and `creator`? Because it currently looks like they are not defined anywhere

Comment: Only `client` can be undefined in this code. If `client` were defined, then `client.guilds` would also be defined and therefore `guild.members` would additionally be defined. Please make sure that your `client` variable is defined; if not, use `message.client` instead. Otherwise, `testserver` may be an invalid ID.

Comment: I have testserver and creator defined in my config.json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities: either `client.guilds` is undefined or `guild.members` is undefined.

If `client` were defined and `testserver` is defined with a proper guild ID, then `client.guilds` would also be defined and therefore `guild.members` would additionally be defined. If `client` were undefined, however, then you would get an error similar to what you are getting (but not quite the same). Please make sure that your `client` variable is defined and has a value; if not, use `message.client` instead.

Additionally, make sure your `testserver` variable is defined and has a valid ID. This is most likely the cause of your issue; did you create a `testserver` variable in this file? Is it a valid ID in this file?

Be sure to separate getting your guild, member, and user, so that you can account for issues like this one much more easily:

```
const guild = message.client.guilds.resolve(testserver);
if (!guild) return message.channel.send("Couldn't find the guild!")

let myMember = guild.members.resolve(creator);
if (!myMember) return message.channel.send("Couldn't find the user!")

const myUser = myMember.user;
```

Not only is this code better practice, it accounts for instances where the guild or user cannot be found. This is important because you don't want your code to continue executing if you weren't able to find your user and store it in a variable, since that is an essential variable and the rest of your code may be dependent on that. Plus, this will greatly assist you in finding out which part of the code is causing issues for you, because it will tell you if it cannot find the proper guild/user.

Comment: After adding the lines of code that you sent, I figured out that I didn't define `testserver` and `creator`, after solving that still the starting issue came... I think I didn't define the client, how can I define it? doing ```const client = Discord.Client();``` doesn't work.

Comment: Well, using `message.client` solved my problem, thanks

Comment: No problem! Yeah, creating a new client with `Discord.Client()` wouldn't work because the `client` represents a bot, so making a new client is the equivalent of creating an entirely new bot. You would need to access the actual `client` that is logged in as your bot, which can be done via `message.client` (as you figured out).